# Azure Devops copy files to server

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, deployment

I have .NET Framework console application that i need to deploy to remote server using Azure devops. I have already deployed .net web apps using artefacts but i can't figure out how to deploy the console app.

The build pipeline is working and it is creating an artefact in either zip file or i can just use all the build files directly. But then what? How to i transfer these files to the remote server, what tasks should i use. I tried the Copy files but i don't know what to put in target folder, i tried the path on the server but nothing happens, it seems the agent is not doing anything.

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is the agent installed in the server you want to copy files to? Is the agent running in the same LAN/VLAN as the target server? Is there a fileshare available to access the server if it's a remote server?

Comment: The agent is installed, i can publish web api on IIS on that server using that agent. The problem is that i don't know what task to use to just publish console app to that server. Should i use the agent or the Copy files task doesn't use the agent at all.

Comment: Why not simply use a PowerShell script task. You don't HAVE to do everything with a task oe extension...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy file to remote server, then Copy Files Task shouldn't be the right method.

You should use [Copy Files Over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Why is one method better than the other?